# D3 appending tbody strangely every other render

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to append a table with d3 to make nested tables.  I have noticed an interesting bug however that has me stumped.  On the first draw of the table, everything looks fine, but on the second draw, it only shows the last element.  On the third, it will draw as expected.  It goes like this every other drawing.  After a lot of trial and error, it is determined that the `append('tbody')` is the cause of all this.

```
    const data = [{
            date: "2018-10-18",
            id: "1234",
            spend: 5.00,
            revenue: .75,
            cpc: .12,
            rpc: .50,
            rpa: .05,
            profit: -5.1,
            Clicks: 34,
            Conversions: 4,
            profitMargin: -2,
            Campaign_Name: "Test campaign",
            affiliate: "test affiliate"
        },
        {
            date: "2018-10-18",
            id: "9876",
            spend: 1.00,
            revenue: 5.00,
            cpc: .02,
            rpc: .10,
            rpa: .15,
            profit: 4.1,
            profitMargin: 7,
            Campaign_Name: "Reed",
            affiliate: "Store",
            Clicks: 34,
            Conversions: 4,
            advertiser: "skdjfh"
        },
        {
            date: "2018-10-18",
            id: "4567",
            spend: .40,
            revenue: .5,
            cpc: .1,
            rpc: .01,
            rpa: .01,
            profit: .1,
            profitMargin: 0,
            Campaign_Name: "Driver",
            affiliate: "Insurance",
            Clicks: 34,
            Conversions: 4,
            advertiser: "skdjfh"
        },
        {
            date: "2018-10-17",
            id: "1234",
            spend: .30,
            revenue: .50,
            cpc: .03,
            rpc: .40,
            rpa: .02,
            profit: .13,
            profitMargin: 2,
            Campaign_Name: "Test campaign",
            Clicks: 34,
            Conversions: 4,
            affiliate: "test affiliate",
            advertiser: "skdjfh"
        },
        {
            date: "2018-10-17",
            id: "9876",
            spend: 4.00,
            revenue: .5,
            cpc: .13,
            rpc: .07,
            Clicks: 34,
            Conversions: 4,
            rpa: .01,
            profit: .71,
            profitMargin: 4,
            Campaign_Name: "Reed",
            affiliate: "Store",
            advertiser: "skdjfh"
        },
        {
            date: "2018-10-17",
            Clicks: 34,
            Conversions: 4,
            id: "4567",
            spend: .64,
            revenue: 5.44,
            cpc: .12,
            rpc: .76,
            rpa: .88,
            profit: -5.1,
            profitMargin: -7,
            Campaign_Name: "Driver",
            affiliate: "Insurance",
            advertiser: "skdjfh"
        },
        {
            date: "2018-10-16",
            Clicks: 34,
            Conversions: 4,
           id: "1234",
            spend: .11,
            revenue: 7.0,
            cpc: .12,
            rpc: .67,
            rpa: .05,
            profit: .64,
            profitMargin: 0,
            Campaign_Name: "Test campaign",
            affiliate: "test affiliate",
            advertiser: "skdjfh"
        },
        {
            date: "2018-10-16",
            Clicks: 34,
            Conversions: 4,
            id: "9876",
            spend: .70,
            revenue: 5.5,
            cpc: .99,
            rpc: .98,
            rpa: .52,
            profit: 4.2,
            profitMargin: -3,
            Campaign_Name: "Reed",
            affiliate: "Store",
            advertiser: "skdjfh"
        },
        {
            date: "2018-10-16",
            Clicks: 34,
            Conversions: 4,
            id: "4567",
            spend: .10,
            revenue: .34,
            cpc: .47,
            rpc: .50,
            rpa: .12,
            profit: 1.3,
            profitMargin: -1,
            Campaign_Name: "Driver",
            affiliate: "Insurance",
            advertiser: "skdjfh"
        },
        {
            date: "2018-10-18",
            Clicks: 34,
            Conversions: 4,
            id: "3344",
            spend: 5.00,
            revenue: .33,
            cpc: .24,
            rpc: .52,
            rpa: .34,
            profit: -0.5,
            profitMargin: 9,
            Campaign_Name: "action campaign",
            affiliate: "camera affiliate",
            advertiser: "skdjfh"
        },
        {
            date: "2018-10-18",
            Clicks: 34,
            Conversions: 4,
            id: "2233",
            spend: 2.00,
            revenue: .5,
            cpc: .2,
            rpc: .70,
            rpa: .46,
            profit: 0.1,
            profitMargin: 2,
            Campaign_Name: "Boogie campaign",
            affiliate: "oogie affiliate",
            advertiser: "skdjfh"
        }
    ];      

 // // // This is a subtotal reducer so each id has its total
    const summary = merged.reduce(function (val, acc) {
        if (!val[acc.id]) val[acc.id] = {
            id: acc.id,
            spend: 0,
            revenue: 0,
            profit: 0,
            Clicks: 0,
            rpa: 0,
            cpc: 0,
            rpc: 0,
            Conversions: 0
        };
        val[acc.id].Clicks += Number.isFinite(acc.Clicks) ? Number.parseFloat(acc.Clicks) : 0;
        val[acc.id].Conversions += Number.isFinite(acc.Conversions) ? Number.parseFloat(acc.Conversions) : 0;
        val[acc.id].spend += Number.isFinite(acc.spend) ? Number.parseFloat(acc.spend) : 0;
        val[acc.id].revenue += Number.isFinite(acc.revenue) ? Number.parseFloat(acc.revenue) : 0;
        val[acc.id].profit += Number.isFinite(acc.profit) ? Number.parseFloat(acc.profit) : 0;
        val[acc.id].Campaign_Name = acc.Campaign_Name;
        val[acc.id].affiliate = acc.affiliate;
        val[acc.id].advertiser = acc.advertiser;
        val[acc.id].cpc = Number.isFinite(val[acc.id].spend / val[acc.affiliateId].Clicks) ? Number.parseFloat(acc.cpc) : 0;
        val[acc.id].rpc = Number.isFinite(val[acc.id].revenue / val[acc.id].Clicks) ? Number.parseFloat(acc.rpc) : 0;
        val[acc.id].rpa = Number.isFinite(val[acc.id].revenue / val[acc.id].Conversions) ? Number.parseFloat(acc.rpa) : 0;
        val[acc.id].profitMargin = Number.isFinite(val[acc.id].profit / val[acc.id].revenue) ? Number.parseFloat(acc.profitMargin) : 0;
        return val;
    }, {});


const nestedData = d3.nest()
        .key(d => d.id)
        .entries(data)
        .map(d => {
            d.header = summary[d.key];
            return d
        });

    console.log(nestedData);// shows the nested data we should be seeing each draw


    var tbody = table.selectAll('tbody')
        .data(nestedData)
        .remove()
        .enter()
        .append('tbody'); //this is the source of the bug

var summaryRow = tbody
        .selectAll('tr.summary')
        .data(d => [d.header])
        .remove()
        .enter()
        .append('tr')
        .attr("class", "tableexport-ignore")
        .on("click", function (d) {
            var entryDetails = $(this).nextUntil(".summary");
            entryDetails.toggle();
        })
        .classed('summary', true);

    addCells(summaryRow);


    // create a row for each object in the data
    var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr.entry')
        .data(d => {
            return d.values
        })
        .remove()
        .enter()
        .append('tr')
        .attr("class", "detail-row")
        .classed('entry', true)

    addCells(rows);
```

Comment: can you post the nested data ?

Comment: you should read up on the join-data in d3, you do it wrong, the `append('tbody')` is not the cause

Comment: @UmeshMaharshi Sure, I just posted the data and the function where it's nested and totaled.

Comment: @rioV8 I have read up on it and see how there is an exit method used. When I tried to use that in my code though, nothing rendered at all.  Can you tell me if there was anything in particular maybe that you were thinking to focus in on?

Comment: I think I actually found the answer, but thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was much simpler than initially thought.  I just have to remove and re-draw the whole table since it seems something was persisting in d3.  HEre's how I solved this:

```
  // clear existing table
    d3.select('#table').select('table').remove();
    // create new table
    const table = d3.select('#table').append('table');

    // // // remove old headers then append new ones in case this is a new date range
    const thead = table.selectAll('thead').data([null]).enter().append('thead');
```

Comment: Don't do that. Removing and re-appending elements is a terrible idea in a D3 code. The problem with your original code is just that `remove()`, which should be not there, and the lack of proper update selections. I advise you to create a running version of your code (jsfiddle, blockbuilder or whatever), then we can just adjust the selections.

Comment: Okay, here's an example of what I am doing: https://jsfiddle.net/mcsmitheslc/h850mu9a/